# Are there any caveats when using column names in 'IN' clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server, where-clause, in-clause

I just had a need to search a particular string value in 2 columns, so my usual approach is

```
SELECT ... FROM ...
WHERE (col1 = 'xyz' OR col2 = 'xyz')
```

But if I had to check multiple values (just for a quick check), say once for 'abc', then 'www', then 'lol', and so on, it is a pain.

So, I tried this and it worked! I never knew this syntax was supported.

```
SELECT ... FROM ...
WHERE 'xyz' IN (col1, col2)
```

Is it ok to use this way? I mean are there any caveats?

Comment: Of course it is okay to use valid SQL syntax in a SQL query.

Comment: Internally `X IN (A, B, C)` gets expanded to `X = A OR X = B OR X = C`, which, together with the symmetry of `=`, allows you to establish equivalency easily. The only thing to avoid (but that's true in both cases) is mixing types in the expressions, since implicit conversions can have surprising results.

Comment: True! Probably it was me who had never explored with a string literal on LHS and column names within IN clause on RHS. :) Glad.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The engine does the exact same operation on both cases. You can see it clearly on the **Predicate**:

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE (
    FirstValue INT,
    SecondValue INT)

INSERT INTO @Table (
    FirstValue,
    SecondValue)
VALUES
    (1, 10),
    (2, 20)
```

### Case 1:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    @Table AS T
WHERE
    1 IN (T.FirstValue, T.SecondValue)
```

[image]

### Case 2:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    @Table AS T
WHERE
    T.FirstValue = 1 OR T.SecondValue = 1
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks EzLo. It was helpful.